# ListView use SimpleCursorAdapter get id error

Tags: android, sqlite

This my SQlite Table
[image]

I want to use `onItemClick` to get id.
This is my code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {                               
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       int id_To_Search = (int)arg3;
       //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).getLong(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ID: " + arg3 , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


       Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
       dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);

       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),DisplayContact1.class);

       intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

but `onItemClick` is passing the database row "name".
HELP ME?

This is my DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET = "street";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY = "place";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_INCOME = "income";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_LEGEND = "legend";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_DATE = "date";



private HashMap hp;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;



public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(
            "create table contacts " + "(_id integer primary key, name text,phone text,email text, street text,place text)"
    );
    db.execSQL("create table contacts2 " + "(id integer primary key,income text, legend text, date text)");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts2");
    onCreate(db);
}

public Cursor select()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor select2()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts2", null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}


public boolean insertContact (String name, String phone, String email, String street,String place) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("phone", phone);
    contentValues.put("email", email);
    contentValues.put("street", street);
    contentValues.put("place", place);
    db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public boolean insertContact2 (String income, String legend, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("income", income);
    contentValues.put("legend", legend);
    contentValues.put("date", date);
    db.insert("contacts2", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
}

public Cursor getData2(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts2 where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
}




public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}



public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name, String phone, String email, String street,String place) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("phone", phone);
    contentValues.put("email", email);
    contentValues.put("street", street);
    contentValues.put("place", place);
    db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public boolean updateContact2 (Integer id, String income, String legend, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("income", income);
    contentValues.put("legend", legend);
    contentValues.put("date", date);
    db.update("contacts2", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteContact (Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts", "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });

}

public Integer deleteContact2 (Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts2", "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });

}

public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}

public ArrayList<Float> getFloat() {
    ArrayList<Float> array_list = new ArrayList<Float>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getFloat(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}

public ArrayList<String> getItem() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts2() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts2", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_INCOME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

}

How can I do get id?

ps. I use `cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("id")` but the error is:
`Couldn't read row 2, col -1 from CursorWindow.`

Answer (score 0):

**1.** In your DBHelper `onCreate()` method, it seems that you have created table `contacts` with `first` column name `_id` and in your other methods like `getdate(), deleteContact(), updateContact()`, you are using `first` column as `id`.

**2.** You are using `cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex("id")` where `id` is an `INTEGER` value. You should use `cursor.getInt( cursor.getColumnIndex("id")`

**Update your `DBHelper` class as below:**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
    public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET = "street";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY = "place";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_INCOME = "income";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_LEGEND = "legend";
    public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_DATE = "date";


    private HashMap hp;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("create table contacts " + "(id integer primary key, name text, phone text, email text, street text, place text)");
        db.execSQL("create table contacts2 " + "(id integer primary key, income text, legend text, date text)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts2");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor select() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public Cursor select2() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("contacts2", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }


    public boolean insertContact(String name, String phone, String email, String street, String place) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE, phone);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET, street);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY, place);

        db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean insertContact2(String income, String legend, String date) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_INCOME, income);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_LEGEND, legend);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DATE, date);

        db.insert("contacts2", null, contentValues);

        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts where id = " + id, null);
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getData2(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts2 where id = " + id, null);
        return res;
    }

    public int numberOfRows() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }


    public boolean updateContact(int id, String name, String phone, String email, String street, String place) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE, phone);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_STREET, street);
        contentValues.put(CONTACTS_COLUMN_CITY, place);

        db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

        return true;
    }

    public boolean updateContact2(int id, String income, String legend, String date) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("income", income);
        contentValues.put("legend", legend);
        contentValues.put("date", date);
        db.update("contacts2", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("contacts", "id = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    }

    public Integer deleteContact2(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete("contacts2", "id = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getFloat() {
        ArrayList<Float> array_list = new ArrayList<Float>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
            array_list.add(res.getFloat(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getItem() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_PHONE)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts2() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts2", null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_INCOME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help~